# After installing any module I get "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Tags: 8

I'm a Drupal beginner and after setting up my site and installing some modules I now have this annoying bug.

After installing any module, doesn't matter what one, I get this white page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL6UO.jpg

Even though it says it has encountered an error, the module actually just gets enabled without any other error logs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3falV.jpg

(In the screenshot I tested it by enabling ban and telephone module, each time after  enabling it in the module list I got an error page. But the modules actually work and there aren't any errors to be found on the logging page.

It's quite annoying to get a white error page instead of the blue loading bar.

Anyone have an idea what the issue here is?

Comment: Can you check log : /admin/reports/dblog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Enable error reporting in Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/show-all-errors-while-developing). This way, Drupal can print the errors and stack traces on the page when the errors occur. Also, consider enabling the module using Drush particularly with `--verbose` and `--debug` options. This prints logging info while enabling the module.

The source of this could be anything. It could be a bad module install script, bad configuration, bad module hook code, or a malformed template (for that page). I usually get these pages when code tries to access non-existent properties or indexes or have modules that don't play nice with each other. This usually look harmless. But if the error cuts into execution and there was data that was still to be saved, it might result in a bad system.

Comment: Thanks. With stack trace I was able to pinpoint the error. It was a database issue where the configuration property innodb_log_file_size of mysql was too low.